# ACE - is it possible to create a pipe using fast path?

Tags: sockets, ace

In windows server > 2012 there's the fast path feature used to create IPC pipes without actually using TCP loopbacks, which are slow:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2012/12/05/fast-tcp-loopback-performance-and-low-latency-with-windows-server-2012-tcp-loopback-fast-path/

Is there a way to make ACE Pipe use the fast-path option on windows?
From what I see in code there's no mention to the SIO_LOOPBACK_FAST_PATH control code and I couldn't find an easy way to pass custom control codes to ACE pipe.

The class is also built in a way that's very hard to inherit from and extend, with one huge open() function that don't get many params and private handles.

How can I try and use fastpath with ACE pipe?

(using ACE 6.1.1 and can't upgrade to newer version)

Comment: You have the source code of ACE so just try to add the enabling of fast path in the correct place and see whether it works. When it works maybe with some tweaks it can be generalized, but depends on the amount of changes you had to make.

Comment: I want to do this without changing ACE source code. Although we do have it in our source control (not always the case) its usually not a good idea to change third party code. Someone might override it when updating version and unknownigly override my change.  Regardless, I did look at ACE's code when trying to figuring it out, and even if I change ACE code its not a trivial change.. Its quite intrusive.

Comment: This is not possible without changing the code, it is a Windows feature that is currently not used yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only possible to use the fast-path option on Windows when you extend ACE with the necessary functionality. When you have a working solution you can submit it to the [ACE main git repository](https://github.com/DOCGroup/ACE_TAO) through a pull request.